# StreamWriter opening and closing

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter

I have a `StreamWriter` that seems to take a long time opening and closing a file. I can visibly see in windows explorer the file size switching between 0KB and 1KB (`StreamWriter` is in a timer). It is 0KB for about half the time, when it should be 0KB (open) for such a small amount of time that I shouldn't be able to see it. Any solutions to fix this?

Comment: Just to add to Darin, what kind of file? What is being done to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you open `StreamWriter` when still is not needed ,so try to use `using` only when you are working with file. this also will improve readability.

for example:

```
using (Stream st = File.Open("file.ext", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadOrWrite))
        {
            using (StreamWriter wr=new StreamWriter(st))
            {
                //your code that needs StreamWriter
            }
        }
```